# Recovery Mode ---FAILED

Tags: recovery-mode

I just try the **Cyanogenmod 12.1 Nightly** and and my android version is now **5.1.1**, whenever I try to go to **Recovery Mode**, it only shows the **Samsung screen** for a seconds (but sometimes twice) and then the Cyanogenmod **booth screen**. I'm doing the right thing (Volume Up, Home button and Power button **at the same time**) but no **Recovery Mode** showing. Please help, I really need to install GAPPS :(

--**SAMSUNG GALAXY S2**

Comment: I thought for the S2 to get into Recovery it was just Volume Up and Power.

Comment: Can't you do `adb reboot recovery`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings. Go in about device and keep tapping build number.
Keep tapping until it says: You have enabled developer options!
Go back and tap developer options and turn on advanced reboot.
Then, hold your power button a little while like you usually do to turn off your device. Tap reboot and tap the recovery option and your phone will go to recovery! After if you want to make everything go back to normal, go to Settings, tap developer options and toggle the switch.